# navigation in not working when [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)] in prism

Tags: c#, mef, wpf-4.0, prism-4

In my prism application I want to make a single shared instance of a view. When I try to navigate the first time it works fine, but when I try to second time it's not working. If I change the `PartCreationPolicy` from `Shared` to `NonShared` it works but it's give me a new instance. Are there any options for another way to do this?

```
[Export(ViewNames.AppView)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)] 
public partial class AppMain : UserControl
{
    public AppMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you mean by "it's not working"? You might also want to explain why you want this to be a singleton.

Comment: U may found actual problem herehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741667/exception-region-with-the-given-name-is-already-registered

Answer (score 0):

You might want to play around with Prism's `KeepAlive` value for your view. This value determines whether the view should be removed from the region when you navigate away from it. You have two ways of doing this:

1. Using the `RegionMemberLifetime` attribute

   ```
   [RegionMemberLifetime(KeepAlive = false)]
   [Export(ViewNames.AppView)]
   [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)] 
   public partial class AppMain : UserControl
   {
       public AppMain()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Implementing the `IRegionMemberLifetime` interface

   ```
   [Export(ViewNames.AppView)]
   [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)] 
   public partial class AppMain : UserControl, IRegionMemberLifetime
   {
       public AppMain()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       public bool KeepAlive
       {
           get { return false; }
       }
   }
   ```

You can read some more about the `KeepAlive` property [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx).